# LINQ: How i can user where condition multi value by array string?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, where-clause, asqueryable

I want to use the linq where condition multi value by array string is `split(',')`
I list data from data file in folder. (not in database)

**Code c#**

```
public List<sFile> GettingFiles(string path)
{
    //Read File in folder
    List<sFile> allfile = new List<sFile>(); 
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] fileinfo = di.GetFiles("*.*");

    foreach (FileInfo item in fileinfo)
    {
        allfile.Add(new sFile
        {
            FileName = item.Name,
            Seq = int.Parse(item.Name.Substring(12, item.Name.Length - 12)),
            PmnCode = item.Name.Substring(7, item.Name.Length - 12),
            Path = item.DirectoryName,
            Size = formatSize(item.Length),
            SizeInt = int.Parse(item.Length.ToString())
        });
    }
    return allfile;
}

public void btnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<sFile> allFiles = GettingFiles(path); //List file in Folder
    string pmnCode = txtPMNCode.Text.ToString(); //AAAA, BBBBB, CCCCC, DDDDD
    string[] subPmnCode = pmnCode.Split(',');
    string totalPmnCode = string.Empty;

    foreach (string item2 in subPmnCode)
    {
        var queryData = from d in allFiles.AsQueryable()
                    where (d.PmnCode.Contains(item2))
                    select d;                       

        //Add Column
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(enmField.NAME.ToString());
        dt.Columns.Add(enmField.SIZE.ToString());
        dt.Columns.Add(enmField.MODIFY_DATE.ToString());
        dt.Columns.Add(enmField.PATH.ToString());

        DataRow myRow = dt.NewRow();

        foreach (sFile item in queryData.ToList())
        {
             myRow = dt.NewRow();
             myRow[enmField.NAME.ToString()] = item.FileName.Trim();
             myRow[enmField.SIZE.ToString()] = item.Size.Trim();
             myRow[enmField.MODIFY_DATE.ToString()] = item.Date;
             myRow[enmField.PATH.ToString()] = item.Path.Trim() + "\\" + item.FileName.Trim();
     dt.Rows.Add(myRow);
        }

        gvDetail.DataSource = dt;
        gvDetail.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Example Data**

```
Pmn Code
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
DDDDD
```

I want query wheer condition by pmn_code is AAAAA,BBBBB, DDDDD
I want show data

```
var queryData = from d in allFiles.AsQueryable()
                where (d.PmnCode.Contains("AAAAA") &&
                d.PmnCode.Contains("BBBBB") &&
                d.PmnCode.Contains("DDDDD")
)
                select d;
```

But i can not query array string by result this.
How can i use array linq?

please help me. Thanks advance ;)

Comment: Can you show the structure of your tables?

Comment: up to now your query returns files which must have such a name : `AAAAA_BBBBB_DDDDD` do you mean may be `||` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

```
var queryData = from p in allFiles.AsQueryable()
                where subPmnCode.Any(val => p.PmnCode.Contains(val))
                select p;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It;s Work ;D

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryData = from d in allFiles.AsQueryable()
                where (subPmnCode.Any(s => s.Trim().Equals(d)))
                select d;
```

Checks if d matches any of the elements in the subPmnCode array. I use trim to ensure that we ignore blank spaces generated by splitting the string into an array using the comma delimiter

Comment: Please provide some information why this LINQ statement solves the problem described in the question.